# Can't reduce the width of like and +1 buttons

Tags: html, css, facebook-iframe

I am trying to set to Facebook like and Google +1 buttons on a page. However, they take too much width:

[image]

I am defining them as following:

```
<table id="plusOneButtons">
    <tr>
        <td id="fbLikeButton"><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLigatures.Net&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21&amp;appId=58053763610" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></td>
        <td id="googlePlusOneButton"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div></td>
        <td id="twitterShareButton"><div><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="LigaturesNet">Tweet</a></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The CSS is:

```
#fbLikeButton {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

#googlePlusOneButton {
    width: 100px;
    background: greenyellow;
}

#twitterShareButton {
    width: 100px;
    background: aliceblue;
}
```

How can I set a proper width? I have already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539092/cant-manipulate-width-of-facebook-like-button), but the solution does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your CSS and include the following property for all ID's `display: inline-block;`

```
#fbLikeButton {
width: 100px;
background: red;
display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign width for your `iframe`

```
 <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLigatures.Net&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21&amp;appId=58053763610" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="130px" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/zdwbh1qh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Although your `<td>`'s have been assigned a width, the elements within them have a greater width and take up more space.
Move the id tags to the `<iframe>` and `<div>` to fix this:

```
<table id="plusOneButtons">
    <tr>
        <td><iframe id="fbLikeButton" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FLigatures.Net&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21&amp;appId=58053763610" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></td>
        <td><div id="googlePlusOneButton" class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div></td>
        <td><div id="twitterShareButton"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="LigaturesNet">Tweet</a></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Izzy's (now deleted) solution worked (i.e., setting `display: inline-block;`)

Comment: I've just realised your answer to the question and undeleted my post for future readers :)